# How to recognize whether a script is running on a tty?

Tags: python, shell

I would like my script to act differently in an interactive shell session and when running with redirected stdout (for example when piped to some other command).

How do I recognize which of these two happen in a Python script?

Example of such behavior in existing program: grep --color=auto highlights matches when running in interactive shell, but doesn't when piped to something else.

Answer (score 92, accepted):

```
import os, sys
os.isatty(sys.stdout.fileno())
```

or

```
sys.stdout.isatty()
```

Comment: Notice: this is a test for stdout. To check stdin use stdin accordingly.

Comment: To check for stderr, use `sys.stderr.isatty()` accordingly.