# How to know if the output is going to a terminal or not?

Tags: python, c, linux, bash, xterm

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Detect if stdin is a terminal or pipe in C/C++/Qt?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1312922/detect-if-stdin-is-a-terminal-or-pipe-in-c-c-qt)

I want to know if the output of my program is directly going to a terminal or is being redirected to a pipeline or a file.

Because if it goes in the terminal i want to output the escape sequences to make color-text, but on a file or in a pipeline those would not be welcome.

I know it is possible because "ls" does it, anyone knows how?

Comment: @Douglas: No, that is for C or C++. Just because the python `os` library has a function with the same name and function does not make that question a dupe of this one. There *may* be a python question here on SO already, dupe to that instead.

Comment: I noticed the C tag but not the python tag, sorry about that. (I actually came across [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/858623/how-to-recognize-whether-a-script-is-running-on-a-tty) while looking for a dupe, but carried on since I was looking for a C one...)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the [`os.isatty()` function](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.isatty) on the filedescriptor of the `stdout` stream or any other file you need to test:

```
>>> import sys, os
>>> os.isatty(sys.stdout.fileno())
True
```

For open files (like the `sys.stdout` stream) the [`.fileno()` method](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#file.fileno) returns the necessary descriptor.

Comment: I guess I can juse use "1" since that's always the file descriptor for stdout.

Comment: @LtWorf: That'd be a shortcut you could use, yes.